# The library is not installed

Tags: python

What do?,I can't install the library,vkbottle,an error appears,bot on Python?

```
Command "c:\users\audra\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Audra\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-82pczn57\\immutables\
\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Audra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
record-_qgx5w6s\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Audra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-82pczn57\immutables\
```

Comment: Can you give more information? I don't understand any of that, and I don't think others will either.

Comment: I wrote in the console pip install vkbottle and I got an error

Comment: And is that the full error in the codeblocks?

Comment: Which Python version do you use? Are you sure? And what is the version of `pip`?

Comment: yes, this is a complete error, the error was more but I read on one site that it is necessary to change the pip version and everything will work fine,I changed to 18.1,and the error was reduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand you exact query.

You said you can't install the library and I can see, you trying to import vkbottle. Have you tried to install the library.

Try using the command:
pip install vkbottle

[Make sure you python environment is active or you can use pip in you terminal or cmd]

Comment: Well, I can't install the library itself, the error comes out

Comment: try this `python -m pip install vkbottle`